# Routing Traffic Through from VPN Client to Switch Network

Tags: routing, openvpn, bridge

[Network Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxeOb.png)

I have two computers, Foo and Bar, connected to an OpenVPN server on Amazon EC2. Both the computers are connected to the Internet via Wi-Fi. The VPN IP addresses are on 13.8.0.*.

Bar's ethernet port is attached to a Net Gear switch. The switch also has Baz connected to it. All of the devices on the Net Gear have the IPs 14.0.0.*.

I need to be able to ping Baz from Foo. I can hit Bar from Foo via the VPN, but am unable to make that final hop to allow the VPN traffic to hit the Net Gear switch.

Bar is a Windows computer, so I tried creating a network bridge between the TAP interface and the ethernet port, and also between the TAP and the Wi-Fi. Both of those efforts resulted in no connection. I had also tried removing the bridge and manually editing the routing tables in the following fashion:

- Added a path to the 14.0.0.* network on Foo, with the default gateway set to Bar (13.8.0.10). Still was not able to ping Baz from Foo.
- Added a path to the 14.0.0.* network on the Amazon EC2 server, with the default gateway say to Bar (13.8.0.10). Still was not able to ping Baz from Amazon EC2.

Is this type of routing even possible via VPN? Any ideas on what to do or what to research would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Should be possible. Is Bar set to route packets? It's called forwarding in Linux, but I don't know about Windows.

Comment: Yup, I made the registry setting for IP forwarding in Windows. That did not seem to make a difference though, which leads me to suspect there's another setting for OpenVPN that needs to be made before it will allow it.

Comment: Found a solution to my issue.

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#scope

The section "Expanding the scope of the VPN to include additional machines on either the client or server subnet." describes the settings needed to access LAN from client computers.